# Is it possible to dynamically control SCM polling?

Tags: github, jenkins, version-control

I'm working on a legacy monolith system. We have an integration between Jenkins and GitHub using GitHubApp. My question is around controlling the trigger of our build job. Please note that we currently do not have permissions to setup Webhooks, so solutions around this approach would not really help us.

**Scenario**

1. Build job is configured in Jenkins with Poll SCM trigger enabled.
2. Workflow of the build job

- Modules are built using maven, unit tests run, and archive artifacts are created.
- If build job is successful, it triggers a downstream job which makes some commits to Git
- As a result of commits in downstream job, another build is triggered.

We are looking to combine the main build job and downstream job which makes the commits. However, we don't really want to trigger a build for commits made via pipeline.

Is there a way to control the Poll SCM feature ?

I was reading through the below link

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/

This mentions an optional poll attribute which can be set to false. However, I am not really sure what to expect with usage of this attribute.